# C++ multiple inheritance - same methods in base classes but with different arguments

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have the following program which doesn't compile:

```
class Interface1
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class Interface2
{
    virtual void f(int i) = 0;
};

class Interface3 : public Interface1,
                   public Interface2
{};

class C : public Interface3
{
    virtual void f() {}
    virtual void f(int i) {}
};

int main()
{
    Interface3* inter = new C();
    inter->f(); // Error
}
```

What is wrong? Does it mean that it doesn't matter if the methods have different argument types?

error: request for member ‘f’ is ambiguous
note: candidates are: virtual void Interface1::f()
...
note: virtual void Interface2::f(int i)

Comment: _What is wrong?_ `enter code here`. Please fix your question. Thank you.

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, always include the actual error in the question body. Please edit your question to include the full, complete and unedited error output (including possible informational notes) in the question. Then also point out where the errors are in the code you show, for example by comment. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem is in the declaration of `class Interface3` (typo **`{}:`** instead of **`{};`** ).

Comment: I modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the two definitions of `f` in the two base types are not defined in the same scope, so they do not overload. There are two separate functions named `f` in `Interface3` and no rule to choose one or the other.

Comment: But how can I fix it, if I want to keep function names?

Comment: Solution: public: using Interface1::f; using Interface2::f; in Interface3 should be added.